# Tailwind: extend theme with a custom _responsive_ spacing

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm new to Tailwind. I'm currently extending the list of components/utilities with a lot of similary purposed classes:

```
/* components.css / utilities.css (doesn't matter in this context) */

.pt-section {
  @apply pt-16 lg:pt-20;
}
.mt-section {
  @apply mt-16 lg:mt-20;
}
.-mt-section {
  @apply -mt-16 lg:-mt-20;
}


.top-section {
  @apply top-16 lg:top-20;
}
.-top-section {
  @apply -top-16 lg:-top-20;
}

/* 
Also: pb-section, mb-section, -mb-section bottom-section, -bottom-section, gap-section...
*/
```

The purpose of this utils is to be able to quickly make e.g. grid gap "same width as the section margin-bottom height" – pretty usable stuff.

I see that it would be much nicer to define a single *responsive* value in the config. I already do that for non-responsive constants describing `body` and `header` heights:

```
// tailwind.config.js

theme: {
  extend: {
    spacing: {
      "13": "3.25rem",
      "18": "4.5rem",
      "header": "5rem",
      "header-1": "calc(5rem - 1px)",
      "body": "calc(100vh - 5rem)",

      "sectionT": ??? should be responsive !!!
      "sectionB": ??? should be responsive !!!
    }
  }
},
```

In this way TW would auto-derive all that I need. I would get `mt-sectionT`, `gap-sectionB` etc. classes automatically.

Is there a way to declare custom responsive (breakpoint-depending) values in the `tailwind.config.js`? Without writing a custom plugin, I mean.

It sounds like a common case, yet I can't find the answer in the docs (checked https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme#customizing-the-default-theme and other pages) or on StackOverflow.